# How do I display the leader's name from a queried value

Tags: sql, razor, webmatrix

I'm using WebMatrix to build a webpage that queries our accounting software and displays the top salesman of the day.

I have 4 Salesmen: sam (salesman 7) Jared (salesman 8) Charlie (salesman 12) Mitchell (salesman 17)

Query code:

```
var ssjb = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM dbo.DR_TRANS where Transdate = 41195 and SALESNO = 7 and subtotal >0");  
var sjdp = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM dbo.DR_TRANS where Transdate = 41195 and SALESNO = 8 and subtotal >0");  
var scjb = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM dbo.DR_TRANS where Transdate = 41195 and SALESNO = 12 and subtotal >0");    
var smms = db.QueryValue("SELECT SUM(SUBTOTAL) FROM dbo.DR_TRANS where Transdate = 41195 and SALESNO = 17 and subtotal >0");
```

Now, I want to evaluate the results of the four queries, and display "Top Salesman: *name*"

I'm lost as to how to evaluate the query then turn the salesman number into the corresponding name.

EDIT: Database structure:

- dbo.staff has lots of columns but the first two are `staffno` (primary key) and `Name`.
- dbo.DR_TRANS contains again many columns but the two we are working with are `subtotal` and `salesno` - neither of which are keys. This table has a scrolling key which is the invoice number.
- `Salesno` is derived from `staffno` (passed through by the app from login details.)

Comment: Also, can someone tell me a trick to make the date code self update? My database stores it as the 5 digit code like "41195". How do I replace the 41195 in all my queries with a 'Today's Date' value that will automatically update?

Comment: much better if you can post the structure of your tables. i guess you have atleast two tables for this, `DR_TRANS` and the table which contains the name of the salesman

Comment: @JohnWoo I could query the staff table for the name, I hadn't tried that. Mainly because I am not confident enough to try a linked table query. DR_TRANS only has a salesman number, called `salesno`.

Comment: you need to link the two tables so that you can get the name of the salesman

Comment: post the structure and i'll help build the query

Comment: @JohnWoo I have done so. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below,  (*I think*) us the query you are looking for. Both tables are joined using `INNER JOIN` through their *Linking* column the `DR_TRANS.Salesno = Staff.StaffNo`. It will list all the `Staff` who has record and which `subtotal > 0`. No need to add a condition for the `staffNo` as they are listed on descending order based on their total transaction.

```
SELECT  b.Name, SUM(subtotal) totalSUM
FROM    DR_TRANS a
        INNER JOIN Staff b
            ON a.Salesno = b.Staffno
WHERE   a.TransDATe = 41195 AND
        a.subtotal > 0
GROUP BY b.Name
ORDER BY totalSUM DESC
```

Comment: Thanks John, but it throws compilation error and gripes about ") expected" no matter what I try. Does it have to be all on one line to work? razor seems different from your post.

Comment: @Bevan If you want that a string spans multiple rows in razor syntax, you must start it with @. Try with `var tsm = db.Query(@"SELECT  b.Name, SUM(subtotal) totalSUM 
FROM    DR_TRANS a 
        INNER JOIN Staff b 
            ON a.Salesno = b.Staffno 
WHERE   a.TransDate = 41195 AND 
        a.subtotal > 0 
GROUP BY b.Name 
ORDER BY totalSUM DESC");`

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT TOP 1 staff.Name, SUM(SubTotal)
FROM Staff
INNER JOIN DR_TRANS on Staff.StaffNO = DR_TRANS.SalesNO
WHERE DR_TRANS.Transdate = 41195 and DR_TRANS.SALESNO IN (7,8,12,17) and DR_TRANS.subtotal > 0
GROUP BY staff.Name
ORDER BY SUM(SubTotal) DESC
```

Result will be the name of the salesman with the largest subTotal.
The `Top 1` will force it to only return the first row.

Comment: `var tsm = db.Query(SELECT TOP 1 staff.Name, SUM(SubTotal)
FROM Staff
INNER JOIN DR_TRANS on Staff.StaffNO = DR_TRANS.SalesNO
WHERE DR_TRANS.Transdate = 41195 and DR_TRANS.SALESNO IN (7,8,12,17) and DR_TRANS.subtotal > 0
GROUP BY staff.Name
ORDER BY SUM(SubTotal) DESC);`

Comment: Try putting it with a "@" and quotes in the beginning and end like this: db.Query(@"SELECT .... DESC ");

Comment: Ok,yes I was missing the " " around the query. Now it does actually run, and displays a name - the wrong one! The displayed name is not the salesman with the highest score, it is displaying the third in line. Odd.

Comment: You can remove the TOP 1 part and see the entire result set. Take another look at the results and make sure the problem isn't with the data itself :)